# Azure App Service Not Working When Upgrade to Production Plan

Tags: c#, azure

I have a WebApp which accesses the resources from a Linux VM. As long as it is a dev/Test Service  plan (Free app plan) it works well and good however the performance is very slow. So when i scale up the service plan to production plan (P2,P3), it is not retrieving any data.

Please share thoughts.
Thanks in advance.

Kind Regards
Srini.

Comment: Do you get a specific error?

Comment: May I know if there is an update in your question? Let me know if I can help further.

Answer (score 0):

When you scale up the pricing tier to P Plan from free plan, the outgoing IP address might change.

[image]

Check the [outbound IP address](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-addresses#when-outbound-ips-change), and consider the IP changes on your side.

[image]